# Running a BrowserQuest local server on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, websocket

I am trying to run a local BrowserQuest server on my Windows XP laptop, but I've got a couple of problems.
You can look at the BrowserQuest blog post here:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/browserquest/

So far, I've downloaded the BrowserQuest sourcecode from github, installed node.js along with the required node.js libraries for BrowserQuest(underscore, log, bison, websocket etc) using the npm install -d.

Now I go to the command prompt and use node server/js/main.js and this is the result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggW7K.png)

Now all seems ok, so I go to the client folder and open index.html in Google Chrome, put a name in and click the Play button, but it's just stuck on the loading symbol (spinner.gif)

So now I go into the console in Google Chrome and this is what it says:

```
App initialized. log.js:14
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Test/client/config/config_build.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input index.html:1
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 text.js:6
181waiting... log.js:22
45waiting... log.js:22
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: text!../config/config_build.json 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout require-jquery.js:80
634waiting... log.js:22
```

Comment: Looks like a cross-origin policy issue with accessing a resource using the `file:///` protocol rather than `http(s)://`. But I've never tried running BrowserQuest...

Comment: Ok, I've installed Xampp and it works now, thanks